# How to remove the smallest value in an Array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to remove the smallest value in an array. I've iterated through the array to find the smallest value but when I try to remove it I get this:

```
    SportStacker.java:111: error: cannot find symbol
            times.remove(slowestTime);
                 ^
    symbol:   method remove(double)
    location: variable times of type double[]
    1 error
```

Which I understand that I'm telling it to remove a double[] when I just want to remove a double at a given index. How do I say I want to remove the double at the index which contains the smallest value? This is my code for my method.

```
     public double removeSlowestTime() {

     double slowestTime;

     for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
        if (times[i] == 0) {
           continue;
        }
        else {
           if (slowestTime < times[i]) {
              slowestTime = times[i];
            times.remove(slowestTime);
           }
        }
     }
     return slowestTime;
```

Answer (score 2):

array doesn't have `remove()` method, you may use `ArrayList` or set that value to some default value, like

```
times[someIndex] = null; // put any valid default value based on your array
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are trying to remove the element doesn't seem right.
Try

```
times = ArrayUtils.removeElement(times, slowestTime);
```

If you want to do a lot of operations like this, a **Collection** or an **ArrayList** might be a better way for you to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove an element from a double array using:

```
times.remove(slowestTime);
```

Arrays are of fixed size and the number of elements cannot be altered once created.

You could build a new `double` array. You could save the position of the slowest time in the array:

```
slowestIndex = i;
...
```

and create your new array on completion of the loop:

```
   double[] newTimes = new double[times.length - 1];
    for (int i=0, j=0; i < times.length - 1; i++) {
       if (i != slowestIndex) {
          newTimes[j++] = newTimes[i];
       }
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't the *j++* be in newTimes[j++] assignment (not in the loop)?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `remove` on an array because it doesn't exist as a method.  There is no simple way to remove an element from an array; I recommend using an implementation of `java.util.List` instead, which provides functionality such as `remove`.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned elsewhere in this answer, unlike in languages like JavaScript and Python, arrays in Java have a fixed number of elements defined when the array is defined.

```
int[] foo = new int[10]; // this array object will always have 10 elements
foo[0] = 42;
foo = new int[20];       // now foo refers to a different array
                         // object with 20 elements
return foo[0];           // so this will return the default int value, 0, not 42
```

If you are looking for a similar type of object to an array, use an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Integer> foo = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // this has zero elements
foo.add(42);                                      // now it has one
foo.add(8675309);                                 // now it has two
foo.remove(0);                                    // now you've removed the first
return foo.get(0);       // returns 8675309, because everything shifted over by one
```

But if you need to frequently remove the *lowest* item from the list, and you have a lot of items and performance is important, your best bet is a [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html). This is a data type that always keeps things in order from least to greatest. That means it takes a little longer to insert an item (`O(log n)`, or proportional to the logarithm of the number of items in the list) but is fast to remove the least item (`O(1)`, or constant no matter how long the list is). In comparison, when using a list, it will take a very short time to add an item (`O(1)`) but you have to inspect every item when searching for the lowest (`O(n)`).

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> foo = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
foo.add(300);
foo.add(100);
foo.add(200);
int a = foo.remove();  // 100
int b = foo.remove();  // 200
int c = foo.remove();  // 300
```